# Problem after installing Ubuntu 20.04 GTK+Icons Yaru theme on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-shell, gtk

I recently installed the Yaru GTK/Icons themes on ubuntu 18.04 following this guide:
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/new-folder-icons-aubergine-as-second.html
by compiling the sources of the Ubuntu/Yaru repository on Github:
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/new-folder-icons-aubergine-as-second.html
However, exploring the new theme, I noticed some problems of misalignment of the elements in the authentication windows, for example:
[image]

encountering the same problem regarding the shutdown -reboot window:

[image]

It could be a problem of the gnome shell theme, in fact if I use another shell theme the problem does not appear even if in this way I cannot have the uniformity of the desktop graphics theme.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This definitely looks like a problem with the GNOME Shell theme.

Answer (score 0):

> It's important to note that the latest Yaru Colors 20.04 theme pack is created for Ubuntu 20.04, which has GTK 3.24.18 and GNOME Shell 3.36. The themes may work with other GTK / GNOME Shell versions, but you may encounter issues.

For more info:
[Yaru Colors Updated With Ubuntu 20.04 Yaru Theme](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/06/yaru-colors-updated-with-ubuntu-2004.html#ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-115:%7E:text=It%27s%20important%20to%20note%20that%20the,versions%2C%20but%20you%20may%20encounter%20issues.)

Follow these steps in order to install and enable communitheme.

1. Install the `communitheme` `snap` on 18.04 by installing `communitheme` in the Ubuntu Software Application or running

   ```
   snap install communitheme
   ```
2. Restart your computer.
3. Click on your user, click on the gear icon and select the "*Ubuntu with communitheme snap*" session from the pop-up, and login.
4. Now Ubuntu is using the `communitheme` including the system, applications, icons, sounds and the cursor.

Reference: [Yaru's Github](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru#using-a-legacy-yarucommunitheme-version-on-ubuntu-1804-bionic-beaver-via-snap-installation)